How to set AWS EBS encryption with terraform and its launch template and without block_device_mappings?
We are new to terraform, trying to use aws provider with terraform version v4.30.
We are trying to find the right setting to encrypt our instance volume.
In this example, we don't use block_device_mappings.
From research, we see different attribute names used for encryption, like

root_encrypted
root_volume_encrypted
root_volume_encrypted_enabled.


Which do we use to set the encryption boolean ? Is what we have below correct ?
If we apply the wrong setting/non-existent attribute, how do we recover to the previous setting ? Do we simply remove the encryption setting and then terraform apply ?

Any help is appreciated.
We have the following -
main.tf
#(other code)
#
#

module "mod_a" {
  source = "../modules/dirA"

  root_encrypted = true
  root_volume_size = 10
  root_volume_type = "gp2"
#
#
}


dirA/ec2_launch_template.tf

resource "aws_launch_template" "generic_template" {

  name     = "Basic T"
  key_name = var.xxxxx
  image_id = var.instance_ami
  instance_type = var.instance_type
#
# (other code)
#
  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"

    tags = {
      Name = "test"
    }
  }

}


dirA/vars.tf
#
# (other code)
variable "root_volume_size"{
  description = "Volume size"
}

variable "root_volume_type"{
  description = "Volume type"
}

variable "root_encrypted"{
  description = "Encrypt"



Terraform comments use the # character, not the :. Your code would be automatically formatted nicer, and more readable, if you used the actual comment character in your comments.

I don't know where you are seeing root_encrypted, root_volume_encrypted and root_volume_encrypted_enabled. You might be seeing those in other Terraform modules (that you are not using), but that would be pretty much irrelevant to what you are doing here. You need to look at the actual documentation for aws_launch_template here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template None of those things you listed are options there. You have to use block_device_mapping to encrypt the root volume.

thx for responding, Mark B. Will change the comment lines. We did look at the doc before we posted. We're unsure how the code is working (without root_encrypted) because root_volume_type and root_volume_size were not found in TR registry you mentioned above unless block_device_mapping block is used
